# show div depend on number of clicks using ng-show, ng-click, ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ng-if

I want to show one div by default. If a button clicked, show the second div and if it clicked again, show the third div.
I tried ng-if and ng-show and nothing happened.

```
    <table class="">
          <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td class="">Year</td>
                <td class="">#1
                   <button class="button-primary" type="button" ng-model="cnt" 
                   ng-click="cnt = cnt+1" ng-init="cnt=1">Add</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
             <tr *ngFor="let year of yearList; index as i;">
              <td class="">{{year}}</td>
              <td class="" ng-show="cnt >= 1"><input class="" type="number"></td>
              <td class="" ng-show="cnt >= 2"><input class="" type="number"></td>
              <td class="" ng-show="cnt >= 3"><input class="" type="number"></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

### The output should be:

```
Default:
year     #1
1990     50
1995     10

after first click:
year     #1   #2
1990     50   30
1995     10   40

after second click
year     #1   #2   #3
1990     50   30   30
1995     10   40   30
```

Also, I don't know how to use function in ts and how to pass number of clicks.

```
<button class="" (click)="addScenario()">Add </button>
```

Comment: You should use `cnt >= 1`. If the cnt becomes 2, it hides the first one and shows the second one

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cnt >= 1`. If `cnt` becomes 2, it hides the first input and shows the second input.

You also need to remove the `=1` from the `ng-model`, because it doesn't allow assignment inside such a condition.

Finally, I replaced the `tr` and `td` with `div`. It might have been because of the code snippet, but because we weren't in a `table` environment, the `tr` and `td` were removed - along with the `ng-show` on the `td`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table class="">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="">Year</td>
        <td class="">#1
          <button class="button-primary" type="button" ng-model="cnt" ng-click="cnt = cnt+1" ng-init="cnt=1">Add</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let year of yearList; index as i;">
        <td class="">{{year}}</td>
        <td class="" ng-show="cnt >= 1"><input class="" type="number"></td>
        <td class="" ng-show="cnt >= 2"><input class="" type="number"></td>
        <td class="" ng-show="cnt >= 3"><input class="" type="number"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

You can also work with an array of values if you'd like, and extend that array on every click

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.inputs = [0];
    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.inputs.push(0);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button class="button-primary" type="button" ng-click="add()" ng-disabled="inputs.length == 3">Add {{inputs.length}}</button>
  <div>
    <div class="" ng-repeat="input in inputs track by $index"><input class="" type="number" ng-model=input></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first solution is not working! I am working with typescript so I have html and ts files.

Comment: In that case, can you show more of the surrounding code in your question. And what do you mean by "not working"? What do you see?

Comment: I mean it shows all the 3 inputs. nothing happens when I click the button! I will update the question to include more code.

Comment: For me it still works. Do you have something like `controllerAs` set?